# Uploading a text file to cloud with Baas using Delphi XE6

Tags: file, delphi, upload, cloud

I'm trying to upload a text file to parse but its not working because I think I'm using the wrong parameters to do the upload in XE6. I feel I need to use something else in place of LStream: TStream.

I followed a tutorial: [XE6 Upload Example](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/sarinadupont/2014/06/20/uploading-images-to-baas-providers-in-delphi-xe6/)

Using the example I was able to successfully upload pictures to parse. I changed the code to this and it isn't working:

```
procedure TForm1.btnUploadClick(Sender: TObject);
var
LStream: TStream;
LFile: TBackendEntityValue;
begin
LStream := SaveText;
   try
     BackEndFiles1.Files.UploadFile('mytext.txt',LStream, 'text/txt',LFile);
     ShowMessage('Uploaded');
     Edit1.Text := LFile.DownloadURL;
   finally
       LStream.Free;
   end;
end;


function TForm1.SaveText: TStream;
begin
  Result := nil;
  begin
    Result := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
     Edit2.Text.SaveToStream(Result);
    except
      Result.Free;
      raise;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You can create a string stream for instance. In your `SaveText` method you would write just `Result := TStringStream.Create(Edit2.Text);`.

Comment: Thank you @TLama. I tried that but I keep having the same error, 'Uknown content type: text/txt'. Do I need to change anything under the BackEndFiles1.Files.UploadFile()?

Comment: Are you sure you about the content type text/txt? Plain text ususally has the type 'text/plain'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you about the content type text/txt? Plain text ususally has the [Internet Media Type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type) `text/plain`. A list of common text media types can be found here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type#Type_text

Comment: Thank you!! That took care of the error I was getting. Very useful stuff!

@TLama Thank you!! Your contribution was huge, an important bit in my code.